# Twitter "@" and "#" linking in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, hashtag

I am trying to convert all **@** and **#** to links when placing the code into my website.

I found some Jquery code that looks to use regex to search for the **@** and **#** but i am unsure of how to accomplish the same thing using PHP.

The code is:

```
  at: function(tweet) {
    return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g, function(m, username) {
      return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + username + '">@' + username + '</a>';
    });
  },

  hash: function(tweet) {
    return tweet.replace(/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/gi, function(m, before, hash) {
      return before + '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + hash + '">#' + hash + '</a>';
    });
  },
```

So if i had something like this:

```
@BobBarker is going to #blahblah and also @BillyBob
```

I would need to search out and do the following:

```
<a target="_blank" 
   class="twtr-atreply" 
   href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=BobBarker'">@BobBarker
</a>

<a target="_blank" 
   class="twtr-atreply" 
   href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=BillyBob'">@BillyBob
</a>
```

Likewise for the hash tag:

```
#blahblah
```

I would need to search out and do the following:

```
<a target="_blank" 
   class="twtr-hashtag" 
   href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23blahblah">#blahblah
</a>
```

Any help would be great!

**update**

I put together some PHP that does a good job at finding the **first** instant of either an **@** or **#** but doesnt keep looping. How would i set up a loop for it?

```
$theTweet = "@BobBarker is going to #blahblah and also @BillyBob";

if (preg_match("/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/", $theTweet, $matches)) {
    $theTweet = str_replace($matches[0],'<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' . trim($matches[0]) . '"> ' . trim($matches[0]) . '</a> ',$theTweet);
    echo $theTweet . '<br />';
}

if (preg_match("/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/", $theTweet, $matches)) {
    $theTweet = str_replace($matches[0],'<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' . trim($matches[0]) . '"> ' . trim($matches[0]) . '</a> ',$theTweet);
    echo $theTweet;
}
```

**update #2**

Answered my own question :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$theTweet = "@BobBarker is going to #blahblah and also @BillyBob";

    preg_match_all("@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@", $theTweet, $matches); //Take care of the http's
    foreach($matches[0] as $tweetsHTTP){
        $theTweet = str_replace($tweetsHTTP,'<a target="_blank" class="js-display-url" href="' . $tweetsHTTP . '"> ' . $tweetsHTTP . '</a> ', $theTweet);
    }

    preg_match_all("/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/", $theTweet, $matches); //Take care of the @'s
    foreach($matches[0] as $tweetsAT){
        $theTweet = str_replace($tweetsAT,'<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/' . str_replace("@", "", $tweetsAT) . '"> ' . $tweetsAT . '</a> ', $theTweet);
    }

    preg_match_all("/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/", $theTweet, $matches); //Take care of the #'s
    foreach($matches[0] as $tweetsHash){
        $theTweet = str_replace($tweetsHash,'<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' . $tweetsHash . '&src=hash"> ' . $tweetsHash . '</a> ', $theTweet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/preg_replace should solve your problem.

Something like this (untested):

```
preg_replace("/ @([\w\d]+) /i", "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$1/\">@$1</a>", $tweet);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question, Patrik.

Comment: You're welcome. Besides that, the regular expressions from you/@Stephan are much better than my quick untested write up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wrap that same behavior that jQuery have into a php function. It's something like this.

```
function writeLinks($tweet){
    //for mentions
    $tweet = preg_replace("/\B[@]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/i", '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name\=$1">$1</a>',$tweet);
    //for hashtags
    $tweet = preg_replace("/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/i", '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search\?q=%23$1>#$1</a>', $tweet);
    return $tweet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What the jQuery script is using is a simple regular expression searching out the @'s and #'s in the tweet. You can do a similar thing with the regular expression functions in PHP.

The function [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) does about the same as the javascript function in your example.

```
function tweetReplaceAt($tweet) {
  return preg_replace("/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/",'<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=$1">@$1</a>',$tweet);
}

function tweetReplaceHash($tweet) {
  return preg_replace("/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/i",'<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1">#$1</a>',$atreplacedTweet);
}
```

Then you can use those functions on your tweets.

`preg_replace` also takes a 4th parameter to limit the amount of replacements and a 5th parameter which will contain the amount of replacements after the function call.

Comment: Thanks for the help there, Silwing!